# How can I know why pictures not uploading in codeigniter form

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, registration

I created a website using Codeigniter and mysql. There is a form for users where they upload their pictures. When I upload a picture to test it, it works fine. But sometimes, when someone else uploads a picture, it doesn't work. How can I know the actual problem?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to debug a file upload issue. Most certain checks to implement in code are:

1. **Filesize** - If media file size is more than the defined size, It should throw some message to the user.
2. **Extensions** - Do list accepted extensions as a text message around file upload button. In the code, make sure, your code accepts those extensions.
3. **Log errors and warnings** - Enable log errors. You can easily debug the issue.
4. Make sure the **directory** where files will upload must have **writable** permissions.
5. On the webpage where the image will be displayed,it must have a proper path like `https://www.DOMAINNAME.com/directoryName/fileName.extension`

Comment: I am already doing Filesize and Extension check. The error comes here is sometimes the file doesn't go in html file input and keeps it empty.

Comment: add **required** attribute with file upload button. It will assure, the field will never be posted empty.

Comment: It is required. That's why some people complain they can't fill the form. According to them they tried it multiple times with different images but no luck

Comment: @FaizanKhokhar please post your code for both, form containing file upload button and backend logic

Answer (score 1):

You can check in php.ini file for following directives:

`upload_max_filesize` & `post_max_size`

If there is low `upload_max_filesize` or `post_max_size` is set it will not upload files.

You can verify both values in using `phpinfo();` method

Comment: Files are not actually uploading in the db. Just storing their path and then retrieve files from the stored path

Comment: Why do you want to store it in DB?
Store it to a directory, save path/filename in db,
while showing, you can retrieving you can fetch name of file from db and pass it to view

Comment: Yes I am doing the same. Storing in directory. But sometimes they don't even go there.

Comment: Check for permissions of directory. It must be writable by webserver.

Comment: Hundreds of people do it right. Only few people complain that they can't upload it.

Comment: Probably broken connection when file is large?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219342/discussion-between-faizan-khokhar-and-ravi).